# zf3 zend navigation helper

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation, zf3

I'm trying to implement my zend navigation from a container in ZF3. I have successfully created navigation with this quick start tutorial introducing navigation directly in `config/autoload/global.php` or `config/module.config.php` files:

https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-navigation/quick-start/

But now I need to make it work these with the helpers to allow navigation modifications from the controller, using the "Navigation setup used in examples" section:

https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-navigation/helpers/intro/

This is my **Module.php**

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Zend\View\HelperPluginManager;

class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function getViewHelperConfig()
    {
        return [
            'factories' => [
                // This will overwrite the native navigation helper
                'navigation' => function(HelperPluginManager $pm) {
                    // Get an instance of the proxy helper
                    $navigation = $pm->get('Zend\View\Helper\Navigation');
                    // Return the new navigation helper instance
                    return $navigation;
                }
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function getControllerConfig()
    {
        return [
            'factories' => [
                        $this->getViewHelperConfig()
                    );
                },
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

And this is my **IndexController.php**

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Navigation\Navigation;
use Zend\Navigation\Page\AbstractPage;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{

    private $navigationHelper;

    public function __construct(
        $navigationHelper    
    ){
        $this->navigationHelper = $navigationHelper;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

        $container = new Navigation();
        $container->addPage(AbstractPage::factory([
            'uri' => 'http://www.example.com/',
        ]));

        $this->navigationHelper->plugin('navigation')->setContainer($container);

        return new ViewModel([
        ]);
    }


}
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function plugin() on array in /var/www/html/zf3/module/Application/src/Controller/IndexController.php on line 50
```

In the tutorial they use the following statement:

```
// Store the container in the proxy helper:
$view->plugin('navigation')->setContainer($container);

// ...or simply:
$view->navigation($container);
```

But I don´t know what this `$view` is, so I assume is my `$navigation` from my **Module.php**. The problem is that, because is an array, it throws the error. The questions are:

- What am I doing wrong?
- Where this `$view` of the tutorial come from?
- What I should pass from my **Module.php** to get it work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Add into module.config.php

```
'service_manager' => [  
   'factories' => [
      Service\NavManager::class => Service\Factory\NavManagerFactory::class,      
    ],
],

'view_helpers' => [  
   'factories' => [
      View\Helper\Menu::class => View\Helper\Factory\MenuFactory::class,      
    ],
    'aliases' => [          
        'mainMenu' => View\Helper\Menu::class,
    ],
],
```

Create Factory in Service Directory:

```
namespace Application\Service\Factory;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Application\Service\NavManager;


class NavManagerFactory {
/**
 * This method creates the NavManager service and returns its instance. 
 */
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null) {
    $authService = $container->get(\Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService::class);        
    $viewHelperManager = $container->get('ViewHelperManager');
    $urlHelper = $viewHelperManager->get('url');

    return new NavManager($authService, $urlHelper);
   }
}
```

Create NavManager file :

```
namespace Application\Service;

class NavManager {
/**
 * Auth service.
 * @var Zend\Authentication\Authentication
 */
private $authService;

/**
 * Url view helper.
 * @var Zend\View\Helper\Url
 */
private $urlHelper;

/**
 * Constructs the service.
 */
public function __construct($authService, $urlHelper) {
    $this->authService = $authService;
    $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;
}

/**
 * Menu render based on user role
 * 
 * @return array
 */
public function getMenuItems() {
    $navItem = array();
    $url = $this->urlHelper;
    $items = [];

    $items[] = [
        'label' => 'Dashboard',
        'icon' => 'dashboard',
        'link'  => $url('home'),
        'route' => ['home'],
    ];

    $items[] = [
        'label' => 'About Us',
        'icon' => 'business',
        'link' => $url('about', ['action'=>'index']),
        'route' => ['about'],
    ];

    $items[] = [
        'label' => 'Service',
        'icon' => 'service',
        'link' => $url('service', ['action'=>'index']),
        'route' => ['service'],
    ];

    return $items;
}
```

Create Helper Factory

```
namespace Application\View\Helper\Factory;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Application\View\Helper\Menu;
use Application\Service\NavManager;

/**
* This is the factory for Menu view helper. Its purpose is to 
 instantiate the helper and init menu items. */
class MenuFactory implements FactoryInterface {

public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null) {
    $navManager = $container->get(NavManager::class);        
    // Get menu items.
    $items = $navManager->getMenuItems();        
    // Instantiate the helper.
    return new Menu($items);
  }

}
```

Create Helper :

```
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

/**
* This view helper class displays a menu bar.
*/
class Menu extends AbstractHelper {
/**
 * Menu items array.
 * @var array 
 */
protected $items = [];

/**
 * Active item's ID.
 * @var string  
 */
protected $activeItemId = '';

/**
 * Constructor.
 * @param array $items Menu items.
 */
public function __construct($items=[]) {
    $this->items = $items;
}

/**
 * Sets menu items.
 * @param array $items Menu items.
 */
public function setItems($items) {
    $this->items = $items;
}

/**
 * Sets ID of the active items.
 * @param string $activeItemId
 */
public function setActiveItemId($activeItemId) {
    $this->activeItemId = $activeItemId;
}

/**
 * Renders the menu.
 * @return string HTML code of the menu.
 */
public function render() {
    if (count($this->items)==0) {
        return ''; // Do nothing if there are no items.
    }

    // Render items
    foreach ($this->items as $item) {
        $result .= $this->renderItem($item);
    }

    return $result;

}
protected function renderItem($item) {        
   // here you can integrate with HTML
   return $item;
}
}
```

After add above codes,just add below code in your layout file :

```
echo $this->mainMenu()->render();
```